# Python style - cleaner way of writing an expression I want to iterate over

Tags: python, dry

I'm still pretty new to programming but with the emphasis on not repeating yourself and Python's emphasis on readability, I was wondering if there's a more D.R.Y way and/or cleaner way to write something like this:

```
dicts = {
    0: set([u'comment', u'dates', u'mychild']), 
    1: set([u'comment', u'created', u'myroot'])
}

def compare_tags(set_dict):
    diff_list = set_dict[0].symmetric_difference(set_dict[1])

    for i in set_dict:
        if set(diff_list).intersection(set_dict[i]):
            diff = set(diff_list).intersection(set_dict[i])

compare_tags(dicts)
```

Specifically not repeating `set(diff_list).intersection(set_dict[i])`

In my last project (using BeautifulSoup) I was similarly repeating code:

```
if address_block.find('div', attrs={'id': '1234'}):
        dl = address_block.find('div', attrs={'id': '1234'})
        pros = dict(zip([x.text for x in dl.find_all('dt')], [y.text for y in dl.find_all('dd')]))
```

But found that I could make it more readable by doing something like this:

```
x = address_block.find('div', attrs={'id': '1234'})

if x:
    pros = dict(zip([x.text for x in x.find_all('dt')], [y.text for y in x.find_all('dd')]))
```

And stacking the variables (x, ...) before I used them.

However, in the first example, because I am iterating over `i in set_dict`, I obviously get an `UnboundLocalError` by referencing `i` before assigning it.

Any advice towards reducing repetition would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the record, in your last example I think `dict((x.text, y.text) for x, y in zip(x.find_all('dt'), x.find_all('dd')))` is even better (and ideally you wouldn't re-use the name `x`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
for i in set_dict:
    x = set(diff_list).intersection(set_dict[i])
    if x:
        diff = x
```